# Adding comments to my custom theme

Tags: customization, comments, single

I would like to add comments to my single.php file. My custom theme is "hand built" and I haven't found the proper code needed to add this functionality. Anyone have the quick and dirty on how to add such a thing?

Comment: Take a look at TwentyTen/Eleven as reference.

Answer (score 3):

While much of comments implementation became simpler in modern WP versions, it still isn't quite make-comments-happen button.

You will need to put together this part of template, most of related functionality is handled by:

- [`wp_list_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments)
- [`comment_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form)

[Check native WP themes for complete start to end implementation](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.3/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/comments.php), although they tend to be a little bulky.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. I'm digesting the code and trying to cut the fat. Thanks for your help. And @kaiser, thanks for the initial direction.

Answer (score 0):

in your single.php template use:

[`comments_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template)

alternatively to working with the comments.php of the default theme, there is still a basic  **comments.php** in this location */wp-includes/theme-compat/comments.php* (although it does not have `comment_form()` implemented).